# Does Server -dev mode store the data in windows

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I tried running the vault server in local with dev mode option. I got a root token which i exported to the environment variables. But once I stopped the server and started it it said *Invalid Request, Unable to start the server with the token `my token.`

Also does the in-memory vault server store its secrets?

If so where does it store secrets in my windows machine? I have exported `VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID` to my environment variables with value s.WC4LYVf6oOyllP6HjR0A3nvo

I tried restarting the server several times

```
C:\Users\user>vault server -dev
==> Vault server configuration:

             Api Address: http://127.0.0.1:8200
                     Cgo: disabled
         Cluster Address: https://127.0.0.1:8201
              Listener 1: tcp (addr: "127.0.0.1:8200", cluster address: "127.0.0.1:8201", max_request_duration: "1m30s", max_request_size: "33554432", tls: "disabled")
               Log Level: info
                   Mlock: supported: false, enabled: false
                 Storage: inmem
                 Version: Vault v1.2.2

Error initializing Dev mode: failed to create root token with ID "s.WC4LYVf6oOyllP6HjR0A3nvo": 1 error occurred:
        * invalid request
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was when ever we start a the vault server in dev mode in windows it generates a root access token. If we export the VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID to the environment variables, it tries to start the server with that token. But since the token was previously used by vault it the server is not allowed to start.

Comment: That is exactly what my issue was, I unset the `VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID` as I'm really only running this as a dev workflow

Answer (score 0):

Because you are running on the dev mode you'll need to unset the token, because whenever you restart the server it generates a new token, and invalidates the previous one. This is how to get it done on MacOS, specifically Big Sur.

Do these:

1. Open the .zshrc file. Issue this command in the terminal `open ~/.zshrc` to open it.
2. In the previous setup, the vault url and token has been added to .zshrc, comment these lines out. These are the lines:

   `export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200`
   `export VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=s.a009oZnrl78a9h1vlRw1kGqL`
3. Issue the startup command on the terminal again - `vault server -dev`
   This time around it'll generate a new token, copy it, paste, and replace the previous token. This is the one to edit and replace -
   `export VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=s.a009oZnrl78a9h1vlRw1kGqL`.
4. Once you've added it, uncomment these vault values in the .zshrc file.
5. Save the file and close, then on your terminal issue this command - `source ~/.zshrc` to refresh/update the .zshrc file.